# Deserialize JSON Date which is in timestamp format to Java Object which has LocalDatetime

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

Project Details:
Spring Boot with Gradle

My java class:

```
public class Sale{
   private String storeNumber;
   @JsonFormat(pattern  = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
   private LocalDateTime saleDateTime;
   // getter, setter
}
```

This object gets serialized as JSON and looks like:

```
{
   "storeNumber": "023",
   "saleDateTime": {
     "date": {
      "year" : 2023,
      "month" : 4,
      "day" : 4
     },
     "time": {
      "hour" : 16,
      "minute" : 28,
      "second" : 45,
      "nano" : 0
     }
  }
}
```

I want to take this JSON and convert it back to the Sale Object using Jackson ObjectMapper.readValue(json, Sale.class);
How will you deserialize it from format shown? Because that's how I am getting it from my DB. I want to be able to write a custom deserializer for that format of date data because we have a lot of production data like that. I will have to find a way to deserialize objects given a date like that.

What I have tried so far:

- added gradle dependency of jackson-datatype-jr310
- registered JavaTimeModule as mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
- made a custom deserializer extending JsonDeserializer and Overriding public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) and registering the same with ObjectMapper as mapper.registerModule(LocalDateTime.class, new CustomDeserializer())

But it's not working. I get the Jackon MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' from Object value (token 'JsonToken.START_OBJECT')

Comment: EDIT: I want to take this JSON and convert it back to the Sale Object using Jackson ObjectMapper.readValue(json, Sale.class);

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, that was a typo. I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat (capital F)

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, you will be able to deserialize it because the format was : "saleDateTime":"2023-04-04T16:28:45" after serializing. Now, how will you deserialize it if the format was what I've shown in my main question? Bcoz that's how I am getting it from my DB. I want to be able to write a custom deserializer for that format of date data because we have a lot of production data like that. I will have to find a way to deserialize objects given a date like that. I hope it made sense.

Comment: Are you storing JSON in your database? In one of my previous projects we did that, partly because we were required to document what JSON we had sent to some other party. It gave us a lot of problems.

Comment: Preferred solution: If the JSON was generated from Java (which it probably is since the date and time can probably only be a serialized `LocalDateTime`), find the library and settings used for that, and it will probably be able to deserialize back. Could even be a Jackson version from before your organization started using jackson-datatype-jr310.

Comment: If the preferred solution in my previous comment cannot work, there’s the more handheld solution: Fit your `Sale` class with a method for unpacking the sales datetime structure into a `LocalDateTime` as described [on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values), section 5 (and definitely other places too). Your method will receive a map of maps of `Integer` with the numbers from JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253282/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-bharadwaj-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Essentially it's your third option - not sure what you missed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import com.example.demo.model.Sale;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode;

public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> { 
public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer() { 
    this(null); 
} 

public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
    super(vc); 
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    
    JsonNode date = node.get("date");
    int year = (Integer) ((IntNode) date.get("year")).numberValue();
    int month = (Integer) ((IntNode) date.get("month")).numberValue();
    int dayOfMonth = (Integer) ((IntNode) date.get("day")).numberValue();
    
    
    JsonNode time = node.get("time");
    int hour = (Integer) ((IntNode) time.get("hour")).numberValue();
    int minute = (Integer) ((IntNode) time.get("minute")).numberValue();
    int second = (Integer) ((IntNode) time.get("second")).numberValue();
    int nanoOfSecond = (Integer) ((IntNode) time.get("nano")).numberValue();
    
    return LocalDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second, nanoOfSecond);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    
    
    String json = "{\r\n" + 
            "   \"storeNumber\": \"023\",\r\n" + 
            "   \"saleDateTime\": {\r\n" + 
            "     \"date\": {\r\n" + 
            "      \"year\" : 2023,\r\n" + 
            "      \"month\" : 4,\r\n" + 
            "      \"day\" : 4\r\n" + 
            "     },\r\n" + 
            "     \"time\": {\r\n" + 
            "      \"hour\" : 16,\r\n" + 
            "      \"minute\" : 28,\r\n" + 
            "      \"second\" : 45,\r\n" + 
            "      \"nano\" : 0\r\n" + 
            "     }\r\n" + 
            "  }\r\n" + 
            "}";
    

    Sale readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Sale.class);
    
    System.out.println(readValue);
}

}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Sale(storeNumber=023, saleDateTime=2023-04-04T16:28:45)
```

Dependencies - nothing special

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```